# Calculate the mask for a range of addresses

Tags: node.js, ip, ipv4, cidr

I have the first and last subnet addres (for example 3.0.0.0 and 3.1.255.255). 
What algorithm will allow me to calculate the length of the mask of this subnet?
Example:

```
3.0.0.0-3.1.255.255
```

By what algorithm can you simply calculate the length of the mask for this range of addresses?

Answer (score 1):

The longest subnet mask is the longest sequence of prefix bits all addresses share. So:

1. convert first and last IP addresses to integers
2. count identical bits, starting from HSB - that's the mask length

IPv4 addresses are really 32-bit unsigned integers - the dot notation is just for us humans.

Step 2 can be done by *exclusive-or*ing both addresses which results in all identical bits being `0`. Then right shift until the result is zero. The mask length is 32-(number of shifts).

In your example:

```
3.0.0.0     = 00000011 00000000 00000000 00000000
3.1.255.255 = 00000011 00000001 11111111 11111111
XOR         = 00000000 00000001 11111111 11111111
turns 0 after 17 right shifts => length is 15
```